# What is the rationale for boost::none_t implementation?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-optional

[Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional) uses a dummy type to allow constructing uninitialized instances of `boost::optional<T>`. This type is called `none_t`, and an instance `none` is already defined in a header for convenience, allowing us to write code such as the following:

```
boost::optional<int> uninitialized(boost::none);
```

Looking at the definition of `none_t`, I noticed that it is in fact a typedef corresponding to a pointer-to-member to some dummy struct:

```
namespace boost {

namespace detail { struct none_helper{}; }

typedef int detail::none_helper::*none_t ;

none_t const none = (static_cast<none_t>(0)) ;

} // namespace boost
```

What are the advantages of using such a convoluted typedef over a simple empty struct like this?

```
namespace boost {

struct none_t {};

none_t const none;

} // namespace boost
```

Comment: I just realized (took me a while...) that this is exactly the structure of the [Safe-Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: You mean you just read the comment Nawaz posted on your answer in June 2012..? ;)

Comment: Nope, rediscovered it by myself :/ Mornings are difficult :/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ah, I had never thought to dig deeper.

One (more or less obvious) advantage to a regular `struct`, is that now `none` evaluates to `false` in boolean contexts.

One advantage over another "evaluates to false" is that pointer to member are prevented from harmful promotion to integral types.

So, I guess that it offers a safe and concise way of having a object that evaluates to `false`.

*EDIT: One should recognize here (hum...) the structure of the [Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).*

Comment: Ah... `boost::none` indeed converts into `false`. :D

Comment: That makes sense, although I don't really see the point in making `none` convertible to `false`. IMHO, it can only gives the false impression that `none` is an `optional`. But perhaps I am overlooking some corner cases anticipated by the library authors.

Comment: Anyway, in other words, it just follows [Safe Bool Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool).

Comment: @LucTouraille: well, I suppose that the same argument could be used against `nullptr`; as they both serve the same role it is somewhat coherent that they behave similarly in many circumstances.