# How to use boost::optional to pass optional input parmemters

Tags: c++, boost

How do I use a API that takes a list of boost::optional parameters? I have not found any documentation that talks about input parameters,

[This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) does not talk about how to handle input parameters. Please let me know what I am missing.

here it is

```
void myMethod(const boost::optional< std::string >& name,
const boost::optional< std::string >& address,
const boost::optional< boost::string >& description,
const boost::optional< bool >& isCurrent,
const boost::optional< std::string >& ProductName,
const boost::optional< std::string >& Vendor)
```

Given that, how should I call it? `myMethod(,,,,x,y)` did not work

Comment: Why didn't it work? What is the problem that you are encountering?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a function such as:

```
void myMethod( boost::optional<int>, boost::optional<double> );
```

You can pass `boost::none` as any of the `boost::optional` parameters to specify "none":

```
myMethod( boost::none, 1.0 );
```

In C++11 or later, an explicit default-constructed object is even less typing.

```
myMethod( {}, 1.0 );
```

If you want to completely omit any mention of the parameter, C++ requires default parameters only *after* specified parameters.

```
void myMethod( boost::optional<int> = boost::none_t,
               boost::optional<double> = boost::none_t );

myMethod( 42 ); // (The second parameter will be boost::none_t
```

You would need to overload your function with different parameter orderings to allow any parameter to be omitted.

```
void myMethod( boost::optional<int> = boost::none,
               boost::optional<double> = boost::none );

// Alternate parameter ordering
void myMethod( boost::optional<double> d,
               boost::optional<int> i = boost::none )
{
    myMethod( i, d );
}

myMethod( 1.0 ); // (The "int" parameter will be boost::none
```

Comment: Thank you,Drew! For some reason, I could not find any documentation on how to use the optional parameters, which is why I had to ask the question.  If you know of any guides that will help learn using boost libraries, please let me know.

Comment: It complains of primary-expression before ',' token when I tried boost::none_t.Should I cast the none_t to each param type?

Comment: I had to use `boost::none` in place of missing arguments. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934626/what-is-the-rationale-for-boostnone-t-implementation) post is relevant

Comment: I'm slightly confused... (1) why are there no argument variable names in the function declarations? And (2) these approaches fail for me when I try to check in the function if the argument was passed in -- i.e. `if (d) { // do stuff }` fails to convert the boost::optional type to bool, and `if (d.get()) { // do stuff }` fails b/c there is no `get` method. Any ideas @learningtocode et al.?

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain please, post that as a question so it (and any answers) get the attention they deserve!

Comment: @DrewDormann https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732272/c-function-with-optional-boostpythonobject-arguments